# Load Selected Primitive Properties in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity

I have following structure in Oracle database:

```
Course(CourseId, Name)
->Student(StudentId, Name, Comment, CourseId)
->Subject(SubjectId, Name, SubjectComment, CourseId)
```

Student contains some of Primitive Properties `(StudentId, Name, CourseId, Comment)` and Navigation Property `(Courses [Linked with DTO name Course on CourseId])`.

Table structure is also same as Entity structure and currenly using Explicit loading to extract the data from Oracle database, using LoadProperty and Load.

I need to load the Collection and Object with selected property, as Load Student with StudentId and Name (without Comment column).

`LoadProperty(Student, s => s.Courses)`, load only CourseId (don't load Name primitive property in Course DTO). So, `Student.Courses.First().CourseId` will be a value and Name will be null as intentionally excluded from loading from database.

`LoadProperty(Course, c => c.Subjects)` load only SubjectId without Name property, even don't go to database to load.

Is there any way to Include/Exclude the Primitive types to load?

Comment: How did you tell it to exclude those properties? Did you set something in the EDMX file for that?

Answer (score 4):

Not with load property and not with entities. You must create custom query and use projection to load only selected columns:

```
var student = from s in context.Students
              select new {
                      StudentId = s.StudentId,
                      ... // Other student's properties
                      CourseId = s.Course.Id,
                      SubjectIds = s.Courese.Subjects.Select(s => s.Ids)   
                  };
```